# Shortest distance b/w virtual line and third point in google map

Tags: c#, google-maps

I have three google map coordinates A(20,-40), B(30,-30) and C(20,-35). I want to draw a imaginary line between A and B and want to find the shortest **distance in miles** of line to point C as described in the image,

[image]

I can do the same with Cartesian coordinates in c#

```
public double FindDistanceToSegment(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double pointX, double pointY)
        {
            double diffX = x2 - x1;
            double diffY = y2 - y1;
            if ((diffX == 0) && (diffY == 0))
            {
                diffX = pointX - x1;
                diffY = pointY - y1;
                return Math.Sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);
            }

            double t = ((pointX - x1) * diffX + (pointY - y1) * diffY) / (diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

            if (t < 0)
            {
                //point is nearest to the first point i.e x1 and y1
                diffX = pointX - x1;
                diffY = pointY - y1;
            }
            else if (t > 1)
            {
                //point is nearest to the end point i.e x2 and y2
                diffX = pointX - x2;
                diffY = pointY - y2;
            }
            else
            {
                //if perpendicular line intersect the line segment.
                diffX = pointX - (x1 + t * diffX);
                diffY = pointY - (y1 + t * diffY);
            }

            //returning shortest distance
            var distance = Math.Sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);
            return distance;
        }
```

but not able to do in google map. Should i need to do new calculation for that? or i can convert Cartesian result to miles? Can anybody help.